# Joining multiple tables without common key

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I currently have 3 tables as listed below. There is no common keys between the tables

Table 1->linkage_Table

```
ID Item         Material       Color
1  keypouch     *              yellow
2  wallet       plastic        *
3  card-holder  leather        gold
```

Table 2->Material_Table

```
ID Name          
1  plastic
2  wool
3  leather
```

Table 3->Color_Table

```
ID Color
1  Yellow
2  green
3  orange
```

I would wish to get the following result set

```
Item         Material    Color

keypouch     plastic     yellow
keypouch     wool        yellow
keypouch     leather     yellow
wallet       plastic     yellow
wallet       plastic     green
wallet       plastic     orange
card-holder  leather     gold
```

I would like to write an SQL statement to join the tables together.

Having * in linkage table would mean that we would retrieve all values from either Material or Color table.

I am really in need of this solution now. Been trying to solve this for more than 5hours. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible approach:

```
SELECT l.Item, m.name, c.Color
      FROM linkage_Table AS l
INNER JOIN Material_Table AS m
        ON l.Material = '*'
           OR l.Material = m.name
INNER JOIN Color_Table AS c
        ON l.Color = '*'
           OR l.Color = c.Color
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67c33/1)

Explanation: the query has to be built so that 'material' and 'color' tables are joined either completely (cross-join), when `'*'` is given in the corresponding field, or by equality of these fields. And that's exactly what we got by using `'ON l.someField = '*' OR l.someField = joined.someField'` clause.

Comment: Coding in specific behaviour for a single column value is bad practice when it could be handled using data (especially since the additional data required is comparatively small) Adding additional records for the other colours means that if another colour is added then it won't automatically be allowed as a selection by the user which may not be the intended functionality.

Answer (score 1):

With example:

```
CREATE TABLE linkage_table (
  id INT,
  item VARCHAR(40),
  material VARCHAR(40),
  color VARCHAR(40)
);

CREATE TABLE material_table (
  id INT,
  name VARCHAR(40)
);

CREATE TABLE color_table (
  id INT,
  color VARCHAR(40)
);

INSERT INTO linkage_table VALUES (1, 'keypouch', '*', 'yellow');
INSERT INTO linkage_table VALUES (2, 'wallet', 'plastic', '*');
INSERT INTO linkage_table VALUES (3, 'card-holder', 'leather', 'gold');

INSERT INTO material_table VALUES (1, 'plastic');
INSERT INTO material_table VALUES (2, 'wool');
INSERT INTO material_table VALUES (3, 'leather');

INSERT INTO color_table VALUES (1, 'yellow');
INSERT INTO color_table VALUES (2, 'green');
INSERT INTO color_table VALUES (3, 'orange');

SELECT l.item AS Item, m.name AS Material, IFNULL(c.Color, l.color)
  FROM linkage_table l
    LEFT JOIN material_table m ON (l.material = m.name OR l.material = '*')
    LEFT JOIN color_table c ON (l.color = c.color OR l.color = '*')
;
```

Returns exactly what you wanted. Not sure if your sample data is lacking 'gold' colour on purpose?

Check at SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d9d3d/4

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use * in a table since a JOIN will not pick up on multiple entries in a target table based on a use of * in a source table you need to have an entry in the database for each record.

ID Item         Material       Color
1  keypouch     plastic        yellow
4  keypouch     wool           yellow
5  keypouch     leather        yellow

And again a similar thing for the colour.
Additionally since you're going to be joining data based on common columns it is usually better (and faster) to use the primary key of the target table as a the column in the source table from which to join. This allows the joins to use the indexes and perform faster.